# Rails: Upon Successful AJAX POST, Return ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm using the following code to create new instances of the Impressions model:

```
var id;
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '/impressions',
  data: {'impression[content]':tags[i].book.impression, 'impression[user_id]':current_user},
  success: function(){id="<%= @impression.id %>";},
  dataType: 'html',
});
alert(id);
```

Upon success, I want it to return the id number of the new instance, but the current function causes a runtime error stating that @impression.id is nil--which, upon reflection, of course it's nil at runtime. How else can I pull the id from the database, though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing this would be for your controller code to render json. For example if your create code simply did

```
render :json => @impression
```

(possibly inside a `responds_to` block) then that data will get passed to you success function. If you declare that as

```
function(data){
    ...
}
```

and set the dataType to json, then `data` will be the json object you rendered and you'll be able to get at all of the impression's properties, including its id. Of course you can render whatever json you want - you don't have to turn the whole object into json.

Comment: This solution seems to work. When I have the success function call 'alert(data)' I get the appropriate id number. Unfortunately, when I have the function set 'id=data', nothing happens. id is unchanged. I've updated my code snippet to show how I'm declaring and checking the variable. Any idea what might be causing this? Either way, I'm checking your answer. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Figured it out! I had to set 'async: false'. Thanks again.